# Дочерняя программа на форме Delphi 7

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

Требуется открыть калькулятор на форме в дельфи, калькулятор должен перетаскиваться вместе с материнской формой и при ее закрытии тоже закрываться. Возможно ли такое реализовать?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var HW:hwnd;
begin
  ShellExecute(Handle,'open','C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe',nil,nil,SW_SHOW);
  sleep(100);
  hw:=FindWindow(nil,'');
  SetParent(Form1);
end;
```

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос: да. Пожалуйста, задавайте более конкретные вопросы описывающие проблему. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вначале разберём ошибки в коде автора вопроса:

```
ShellExecute(Handle,'open','C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe',nil,nil,SW_SHOW);
```

Ну, запустите вы приложение, но после этого вам придётся ломать голову, как найти оконный хэндл (HWND), а вы даже не знаете pid процесса.

```
sleep(100);
```

Ждём, пока запустится калькулятор? А если компьютер жутко загружен, и калькулятор будет открываться не 0.1 секунды, а дольше? Специально сейчас запустил калькулятор на загруженной счётом машине, получилось более 4х секунд :)

```
hw:=FindWindow(nil,'');
```

Вы пытаетесь найти HWND, указывая в качестве параметра пустую строку? А ведь это заголовок окна, у меня калькулятор имеет в его качестве гордую строку "Calculator".

```
SetParent(Form1);
```

А это тут к чему? Нет, идея-то понятна, но вот попытка реализации...

Что же нужно, чтобы выполнить ваше задание:

1. вы должны запустить процесс и получить его ProcessID, например, через CreateProcess
2. теперь вам нужно узнать значение HWND вашего калькулятора. Да, его можно найти через FindWindow, но вдруг у пользователя до этого уже был запущен калькулятор?
3. А вот теперь уже можно будет воспользоваться, но не SetParent(Form1), а вполне себе Winapi.Windows.SetParent(winhandle,Handle)

Проще всего оформить вызов внешнего приложения через процедуру, вдруг неоднократно пригодится:

```
procedure StartMyCommand(command:string); // command - наша командная строка, например, 'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe'
var
  isGood: LongBool;
  StartUpInfo: TStartUpInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
  cmd:PChar;
begin
  cmd:=PChar(command); // превращаем командную строку в PChar
  FillChar(StartUpInfo, SizeOf(TStartUpInfo), 0); // подготавливаем переменные для запуска
  with StartUpInfo do
  begin
    cb := SizeOf(TStartUpInfo);
    dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
    wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;
  isGood := CreateProcess(cmd, '', nil, nil, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartUpInfo, ProcessInfo); // выполняем запуск приложения
  if isGood then // проверка на успешный запуск
  with ProcessInfo do begin
    WaitForInputIdle(hProcess, INFINITE); // ждем завершения инициализации, вот так надо правильно, а не ваш Sleep(100)
    CloseHandle(hThread); // закрываем дескриптор процесса, он нам не нужен
    CloseHandle(hProcess); // закрываем дескриптор потока, тоже не нужен больше
    EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, LPARAM(dwProcessID)); // запускаем перебор окон, близких к вершине просмотра, нам понадобится определить callback-фунцию EnumWindowsProc для сервисных функций 
  end
else 
   begin
     // тут уж сами ошибки обрабатывайте
   end;
end;
```

Определяем переменную, которая вернёт нам HWND нужного нам окна и функцию EnumWindowsProc для её отлова (помним, что определение переменной и эта функция должны в тексте программы находиться ДО нашей процедуры StartMyCommand):

```
var
  WinHandle: HWND;

function EnumWindowsProc(hWnd:HWND; lPar:LPARAM):boolean;
var
  bContinue:boolean;
  dwProcessID:integer;
begin
  bContinue:=true;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, @dwProcessID);
// перебираем процессы и, как только процессID совпадает с желаемым, определяем нужное нам окно
    if (dwProcessID = DWORD(lPar)) then
       begin
         bContinue := FALSE;
         WinHandle:=hWnd;
       end;
    Result:=bContinue;
end;
```

Вот, и всё. `HWND` мы получили, выставляйте `Parent`, можно поиграться с `MoveWindow` и `SetWindowRgn`, если нужно конечно. Но с этим уж постарайтесь разобраться сами, MSDN вам в помощь.

P.S. Мог чего-то по мелочи накосячить, поскольку писал в блокноте, а не в IDE.